# What's the formula for converting a RGB image to the Sepia Filter?

Tags: python, rgb

I want to take the pixel value of a RGB image and convert them to Sepia in Python. What's the formula for it?

Comment: yes it does thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `R` is the amount of red in the pixel, `B` the amount of blue and `G` the amount of green, we can compute the following;

```
tr = 0.393R + 0.769G + 0.189B
tg = 0.349R + 0.686G + 0.168B
tb = 0.272R + 0.534G + 0.131B
```

Then values of red, green and blue for your new sepia-ed pixel will be:

```
If tr > 255 then r = 255 else r = tr
If tg > 255 then g = 255 else g = tg
If tb > 255 then b = 255 else b = tb
```

I'll let you write the Python code, it shouldn't be that hard !